# Will a database be copied into a "new one" when it get's renamed?

Tags: db2

Like the title says... will a database be fully copied to a new one when it get's renamed?

Comment: What database do you use? This is how it is implemented for this type of database.

Comment: @Marco AS400 DB2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the database won't be copied. To copy the database there is copy option. Rename option will change the name of database only

Comment: okay, gonna let it open if someone else has another approach.